# What should be "session_id" value GA4 via MP

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

What should be "session_id" value GA4 via MP in event params when I send GA4 event via MP (POST request)?

```
{
"client_id": "x",
"events": [
  {
    "name": "click_premium",
    "params": {
      "engagement_time_msec": "1",
      "session_id": "???" // what should be here? Random or calculated value ?
    }
  }
]
}
```

And I can't get it from gtag, because I send GA from chrome extension and can't insert gtag script to document.

I don't get it and documentation doesn't really helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to either extract session_id from the GA4 cookie or generate it yourself.

If you decide to generate it, you can base it on a set of values such as IP address (anonymized by removing last octet!), browser user agent, day, hour, minute (or block of minutes, e.g. 0-29 and 30-59), it really depends on your session definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is clearer for me now

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consult the documentaiton to understand what the session id is.  [docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11986666#sessions&zippy=%2Cin-this-article)

- To determine the session that each event comes from, the session_start event generates a session ID and Analytics associates the session ID with each subsequent event in the session
- A session will end when there has been more than a 30-minute period of inactivity (depending on the session timeout settings)
- Sessions are not restarted at midnight or when new campaign parameters are encountered
- If a user comes back after a session timeout, it will start a new session

What you use and how you create it is really up to you and your app.